# C++ calling constructor for passing new object causes missing data

Tags: c++, class, constructor, sfml

So I have a class `RadianButtonComponent` and I want to have a vector contain an uncertain number of objects of `RadianButtonComponent`.  However, I want to do something along the lines of -- `myButtons.push_back(RadianButtonComponent(font, "text", ...))` However, when I do this, I lose some information.  I know that calling the constructor like that will basically make a temporary object.  However, when I try to pass font over (which is a pointer to an address) I lose that address even if the pointer is passed by reference from an outside source.

(To give some code to help explain)

```
class RadianButtonComponent
{
private:
    sf::Font myFont;
    sf::Text myText;
    /* ... */

public:
    RadianButtonComponent();
    RadianButtonComponent(sf::Font& font, std::string text, ...)
    {
        myFont = font;
        myText.setFont(myFont);
        myText.setString(text);
    }
    ~RadianButtonComponent();
};

int main()
{
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("...");

    //No memory lost, font address not removed.
    RadianButtonComponent workingButton(font, "Text", ...);

    //Memory lost, font address not found.
    RadianButtonComponent brokenButton;
    brokenButton = RadianButtonComponent(font, "Text", ...);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I know that when the constructor is called like this it basically makes a temporary object of the class, however, if `BrokenButton` is set to this temporary object and its pointer to font is set to the address from the outside font source's address it should work (at least I think it should), but I still lose the address.

Why does this happen and how can this be fixed? Is there something more I should know about what happens when the constructor is called like this?

(I feel that I have given enough information, but if you need more code to help pinpoint the problem I will update it asap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following the "rule of 3".  Your class lacks a user-defined assignment operator and copy constructor to handle these `sf_Font` types.  So when you do this:

```
RadianButtonComponent brokenButton;
brokenButton = RadianButtonComponent(font, "Text", ...);  // assignment operator is called
```

Then all bets are off when `=` is applied, as you're doing on the second line above.  Since your explanation (and the other answer's explanation) of what an `sf_Font` is, your RadianButtonComponent may or may not be safely placed in a container such as `std::vector`.  The object *must* have the correct copy semantics beforehand.

In other words, if this program does not work correctly, then you need to fix it so it does work *before* even considering placing it in a vector:

```
int main()
{
   RadianButtonComponent b1(font, "Text", ...);
   RadianButtonComponent b2 = b1;
   RadianButtonComponent b3(font, "Text2", ...);
   b3 = b1;
}
```

That program (and any program that can be a variant of the above) *must* be able to compile and run without any flaws (including clean up of memory).

If the program doesn't work, then the suggestion of using a vector of smart pointers is a possible solution instead of a `vector<RadianButtonComponent>`.

Comment: This certainly helps me a lot.  I didn't know that there was a copy constructor and thought that the normal constructor was used when called as such.  If there is anything about copy constructors that I should be warned about or something do let me know, I will begin some more research now.

Answer (score 2):

From the spec:

> It is important to note that the `sf::Text` instance doesn't copy the font that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it. Thus, a `sf::Font` must not be destructed while it is used by a `sf::Text` (i.e. never write a function that uses a local `sf::Font` instance for creating a text).

So in the copy constructor, you must copy the font and then reset the font of the new object's myText.

Alternatively disable the copy constructor, and create a vector of smart pointers of your buttons.

Comment: Do I not do that in the code above? That is why I pass an outside sf::Font so that the address will still exist.  Do you mind elaborating a bit more for me?

Comment: @Uulamock The sf::Font is stored in the button object as a copy at location A, and the sf::Text refers to location A. When you copy your button object, the second button now has sf::Font at location B, but the copied sf::Text still refers to location A. You must call `myText.setFont(myFont)` again in the copy constructor/assignment operator to update it with the NEW object's copy of sf::Font at location B.

Comment: That certainly makes more sense, I never learned about copy constructors when I asked this question and just thought that the normal constructor was just called and that it automatically set all the variables to the new one. Thanks for the clarification. It helps a ton.

Comment: @Uulamock The automatically generated copy constructor, copies each member from one to the other. The problem is it's a bit dumb, and doesn't understand that sf::Text should refer to the sf::Font in the new object.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about this problem more, storing sf::Font inside an object is the wrong approach. I suggest you have a global `std::map<std::string, sf::Font>` data structure somewhere, which stores the fonts with their font name. (You could also use an int or enum id instead of a string). A button's constructor will take an sf::Font reference, which originates from this map, but does not copy it. Therefore all sf::Text objects will refer to the sf::Font instance stored permanently in your map.

Comment: That is some pretty good advice, Thanks for the tip. I am still learning how to make cleaner code so this really does help me some.